# How to handle the SAMLResponse from OKTA?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, okta

I am trying to implement the SSO via OKTA. And I can get the SAMLResponse text by

```
string rawSamlData = Request["SAMLResponse"];
```

Convert the string to XML Format by

```
     if (rawSamlData.Contains("%"))
        {
            rawSamlData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(rawSamlData);
        }
        byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);
        string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);
```

The information of the user is included in the string samlAssertion, Such as X509Certificate, FirstName, LastName, Email etc. The question is how to check whether it is validate or not?

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse SAML data on your own, unless you are willing to invest a lot of time in getting the security right.

Kentor.AuthServices is an open source .NET SP implementation that is compatible with Okta. There's even specific [documentation](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/IdentityServer3Okta.md) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use WS-Federation for SSO in .NET? Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx. To use Okta for [Step 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6), you can [create a Template WS-Fed app in Okta](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/29510977-Configuring-the-Okta-Template-WS-Federation-Application) and use the provided web.config provided under the Sign On tab.

If SAML is absolutely required, there are some frameworks you can use to help such as http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net/. Also check out http://www.twobotechnologies.com/blog/2014/01/sp-init-with-wif.html for SP init SAML and http://travisspencer.com/blog/2010/09/idp-initiated-sso-using-wif.html for IdP init SAML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I received the SAMLResponse from the okta via the Form. What I need to do is to check whether the request is validate or not. If the request is validate, I will skip the login page and let the user login in automatically. How can I make sure the request is validate? In other words, How should I use the certificate and token?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of integrating with okta and handling SAML response your self, you can use an apache module called [mod_auth_mellon](https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon).
Here are simple steps to [install it in ubuntu](http://mkchendil.blogspot.com.eg/2015/03/okta-integration-with-apache-usingmodauthmellon.html)